# How to alter kinesis consumer properties in spark streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

Here is the KinesisReceiver [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/kinesis/KinesisReceiver.html). Here all the default values of [KinesisClientLibConfiguration](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/clientlibrary/lib/worker/KinesisClientLibConfiguration.java) are used.

Is there a way to change the default values using a properties file in spark streaming application?